# why this sql can execute successful after prepare?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mybatis, spring-mybatis

hum, today I found a problem about sql

```
SELECT * FROM tb_users where deleteFlag != 1 ORDER BY createTime LIMIT 0, ?
```

from mybatis xml:

```
<select id="findListByNearly" resultType="org.destiny.model.User">
    SELECT
        <include refid="Base_Column_List"/>
    FROM tb.users
    WHERE status != 0
    ORDER BY createTime
    LIMIT 0, #{count}
</select>
```

I falsely invoke by

```
count = -1
```

it works fine
but when I executed immediately

```
SELECT * FROM tb_users where deleteFlag != 1 ORDER BY createTime LIMIT 0, -1
```

MySQL returned error information like this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1' at line 1
```

I know it won't work if I immediately execute by `LIMIT 0, -1` cause wrong syntax,

**but why it can work after prepare?**

the log for springboot:

```
==>  Preparing: SELECT id, typeName, standardWeight, standardCube, standardHeight, status, createTime, updateTime FROM TB_YX_TMS_CAR_TYPES WHERE status != 0 AND (standardCube > 19.4) ORDER BY (standardCube - 19.4) LIMIT 0, ? 
==> Parameters: -1(Integer)
<==    Columns: id, typeName, standardWeight, standardCube, standardHeight, status, createTime, updateTime
<==        Row: 4, type4, 0.0, 19.7, null, 1, 0, 0
<==        Row: 2, type2, 0.0, 20.2, null, 1, 0, 0
<==        Row: 3, type3, 0.0, 20.9, null, 1, 0, 0
<==      Total: 3
```

=====================================================================

I tested on mysql client, find it doesn't work after mysql-prepare:
[when I invoked by -1, it returns a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3AZt.jpg)

but why it works in mybatis?

Comment: two people has posted exact same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554553/why-this-sql-can-execute-after-prepare

Comment: What does a prepared query return? An empty result set?

Answer (score 0):

Because, correct syntax for [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) keyword is

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. ***The offset of the initial row is 0*** (not 1):

As per documentation, you ***can't*** have `negative` `offset`.

Comment: Thanks!
it's definitely to the syntax of offset
but I want to know more about why this sql can work after prepare, when 

    SELECT * FROM tb_users where deleteFlag != 1 ORDER BY createTime LIMIT 0, ?

invoked by argument `-1`，it seems return all the results as `limit` doesn't exist.

And I display the log of springboot in question, You can have a look at your convenience.